# Python requests BaseAuth class and custom POST data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using the Python Requests libray to login in a site. To this end, I need to capture some data of the login page and then make a POST request to the same page with it.

My first approach was something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from contextlib import contextmanager

def get_data(soup, ids, **kwargs):
    pass

@contextmanager
def login_session(username='user', password='pass'):
    auth = {'username': username, 'password': password}
    url = 'http://example.com/Login.aspx'
    ids = ('#this', '#other')

    with requests.Session() as s:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)
        s.post(url, data=get_data(soup, ids, **auth))
        yield s

with login_session() as s:
    page = s.get('http://example/protected.aspx').content
```

However, I noticed requests provides a `BaseAuth` class to make [custom authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#new-forms-of-authentication).

So, I tried to implement my own `CustomAuth`

```
import requests

class CustomAuth(AuthBase):

    ids = ('#this', '#other')
    url = "http://example.com/Login.aspx"

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def _get_data(self, soup):
        pass

    def __call__(self, r):
        '''Prepare data for POST request'''

        with requests.Session() as s:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(self.url).content)
            r.data = self._get_data(soup)
        return r

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(CustomAuth.url, auth=CustomAuth('user','pass'))
```

But it doesn't work as expected. 
**So, is it possible to use the `BaseAuth` for this case?**

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use selenium library to log in the website and to save the cookies. Then **pass the cookies from selenium to requests library.**In this way, you can save lots of time and efforts.